# Python Class Constructor Methods

Tags: python, class, variables, random, constructor

So I have this code:

```
import random

class Node():

    def __init__(self, name, content):
        self.name = name
        self.mac_address = self.generate_mac
        self.content = content

    def generate_mac():
       return  "%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x" % (
        random.randint(0, 255),
        random.randint(0, 255),
        random.randint(0, 255),
        random.randint(0, 255),
        random.randint(0, 255),
        random.randint(0, 255)
        )


class Switch():

    def __init__(self, name, content):
        self.name = name
        self.file = name + ".txt"
        self.content = content

    def write_table(self, send_node, recv_node):
        f = open(self.file, 'w')
        f.write(send_node.mac_address() + " " + send_node.name[-1])
```

I want every node to have a fixed MAC address which I can get later using `node_instance.mac_address`. But every time I do that, I'll be generating a new address. How to I keep it fixed?

Comment: Don't generate it randomly every time? It's not a good way to generate valid MACs anyway.

Comment: add the parenthesis in the constructor at `generate_mac`. It should become `self.generate_mac()`

Comment: Google or search [so] for mac generation, after the whole random vs persistent bit is sorted out to see how to safely generate a random MAC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `__init__` method you *meant* to write

```
self.mac_address = self.generate_mac()
```

and in the call near the bottom, write

```
f.write(send_node.mac_address + " " + send_node.name[-1])
```

You had written

```
self.mac_address = self.generate_mac
```

which meant that `self.mac_address` was actually a method. You want it to be set once, during construction, as a string property instead of a method.

Comment: That looks like a comment.

Comment: Really? A comment asks for clarification of the question. An answer tells the OP what he or she wants to know. Am I wrong about this?

Comment: Hmmm, looks like you may be right. I just landed on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46698861/syntaxerror-unexpected-identifier-for-an-asynchronous-function where Pointy pointed out a missing comma in a comment instead of an answer.... Although that was fixing a syntax error. Close call, but I see what you are saying.

Comment: Initially the answer was just about the typo. The current answer, I'm not really sure that's what the poster is asking i.e. it's not obvious it's about the typo but I suppose they can chime in.

Comment: Should have seen that. Sorry for the bother over such a simple thing.

Answer (score 0):

```
self.mac_address = self.generate_mac()
```

Instead of assigning a function to the variable, call the function.  Then on the object creation: node_instance = Node() will run the **init** and generate a Mac address.  mac_address will now be a string (the result of the function call) and all future calls to node_instance.mac_address will be the string.